# Makefile - use the same variable twice in a single row

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a recipe:

```
define postmake 
ZZZ=$(strip $(1))
echo $(ZZZ) $(ZZZ)
endef
```

$(1) is the first argument passed to it. When the recipe is called the echo command prints only the first expansion of the variable. The second one is lost. **How can I expand/use the same variable twice in the same row?**

I need it for `objcopy something.elf -O binary something.bin` (`something` is the variable, in my case the second file becomes just `.bin` and is obviously wrong).

**UPDATE:** I use [Boilermake](https://github.com/dmoulding/boilermake) as the template. Everything else besides this recipe works perfectly fine. I invoke the `postmake` recipe like this:

```
TARGET :=main.elf
TGT_POSTMAKE := ${postmake}$(TARGET)
```

Comment: Please show an example of how you're using this `postmake` variable in your makefile.  That's _critical_ to understanding what's happening.  It's all about expansion order.  I'm quite sure the above is not right but I can't tell you what it SHOULD be without seeing how it's used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in Boilermake when specifying `TGT_POSTMAKE` only the recipe name can be defined.
Correct way:

```
TGT_POSTMAKE := $(postmake)
```

Incorrect way:

```
TGT_POSTMAKE := $(postmake) $(TARGET)
```

Then in the `postmake` recipe instead of arguments like `$(1)` simply `$(TARGET)` can be used.